# ¿Cómo programar el conversor de temperatura de Google usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, events

Estoy luchando hace varios días intentando recrear el conversor de temperatura de Google.

Lo que me interesa particularmente (y lo que no estoy pudiendo lograr) es que el usuario pueda ingresar la temperatura en cualquiera de los dos inputs, de manera que aquel input donde el usuario ingrese el valor pase a funcionar de input y en consecuencia el input restante pase a ser el output.

Debajo les dejo hasta donde llegué basándome levemente en el programa de otro usuario (tal usuario no lograba lo que yo me propongo pero si me dio ideas respecto a como llevar acabo mi cometido).

Desde ya, ¡gracias!

// defino que 'input' va a ser el de entrada y cual el de salida, así como los 'select' que les corresponden

```js
var entrada; 
var inputSel;
var salida;
var outputSel;

function onChange(num) {
    if(num == 'uno') {

        entrada = document.getElementById('input1').value;
        inputSel = document.getElementById('sel1').value;
        salida = document.GetElementById('input2');
        outputSel = document.getElementById('sel2').value;
    }else if (num == 'dos') {
        entrada = document.getElementById('input2').value;
        inputSel = document.getElementById('sel2').value;
        salida = document.GetElementById('input1'); 
        outputSel = document.getElementById('sel1').value;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'error onChange function';
    }
}



function tempCalc(valNum) {

    valNum = parseFloat(valNum);

    if (valNum != 0) {
        if(inputSel == 'cel' && outputSel == 'fahr') {
            salida.value = (valNum * 9/5) + 32;
        }else if(inputSel == 'cel' && outputSel == 'kel') {
            salida.value = valNum + 273.15;
        }else if{
            document.getElementById('error2').innerHTML = 'error tempCalc function';
        }
    }else {
        document.getElementById('error3').innerHTML = 'valNum es 0';
    }

}
```

```html
<div id='box'>
  <p class="temp-config">

      <input id="input1" type="number" oninput="onChange('uno'); tempCalc(entrada)" onchange="onChange('uno'); tempCalc(entrada)"> 
      <select id="sel1" onchange="tempCalc(entrada)">
          <option value="fahr">Fahrenheit</option>
          <option value="cel" selected="selected">Celsius</option>
          <option value="kel">Kelvin</option>
      </select>
  </p>
  <div id="igual">=</div>
  <p class="temp-config">
      <input id="input2" type="number" oninput="onChange('dos'); tempCalc(entrada)" onchange="onChange('dos'); tempCalc(entrada)">
      <select id="sel2" onchange="tempCalc(entrada)">
          <option name="fahrenheit" value="fahr" selected="selected">Fahrenheit</option>
          <option name="celsius" value="cel">Celsius</option>
          <option name="kelvin" value="kel">Kelvin</option>
      </select>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser con un `select`? Podrías simplificar poniendo solamente tres inputs y convirtiendo los restantes. O sea, si el usuario escribe un valor en el input de `Celsius`, convierte ese valor a `Kevin` y a `Fahrenheit` y los muestra en sus respectivos inputs.

Comment: Tienes varios errores en tu código que se pueden ver en la consola. Tienes un `else if` sin condición, tienes algún error de sintaxis `document.` **`G`** `etElementById('id')` (la G deberia ser minus como en los otros casos). Ademas de esto solo has hecho el camino para calcular de `Celsius` a `Fahrenheit` o a `Kelvin`. Por lo demás, vas bien :)

Comment: primero deberias encerrar todo tu codigo en window.onload = ()=>{}, depronto primero se carga el script que el código. Luego ver que otros errores te da o si funciona

Comment: @A.Cedano ya logré hacer esto que planteas pero me propuse copiar tal cual es el que tiene Google.

Comment: @x3kagainstSEbehavior gracias, ya corregí eso pero aún así no está funcionando.

Comment: @FranciscoGuerrero Edita la pregunta para actualizar el código. Como te dije te faltaba aun la lógica para calcular el resto.

Comment: @Riven ¿Podrías darme un ejemplo de como y donde debería escribir eso? Busqué pero no termino de entender donde debería escribir eso y de que manera incluir las dos funciones ya que necesito que se ejecuten sólo cuando se interactua con los inputs o los select. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

```js
/* Capturamos los elementos en variables */
let cboconv1 = document.getElementById('cboconv1');
let cboconv2 = document.getElementById('cboconv2');
let txtconv1 = document.getElementById('txtconv1');
let txtconv2 = document.getElementById('txtconv2');

/* Creamos una función con 4 parametros */
function gz_convertir(cboval1, cboval2, txtval1, txtval2) {
  /* Creamos un Switch que evalue el valor del primer cbo */
  switch (cboval1.value) {
    /* Si es Celcius */
    case 'cel':
      /* y el segundo combo es cualquiera de los otros valores que realice su respectiva formular */
      if (cboval2.value == 'fah') {
        txtval2.value = parseFloat(txtval1.value * 9 / 5) + 32;

      } else if (cboval2.value == 'cel') {
        txtval2.value = txtval1.value;

      } else if (cboval2.value == 'kel') {
        txtval2.value = parseFloat(txtval1.value) + 273.15;
      }
      break;

      /* Si es Fahrenheit */
    case 'fah':

      if (cboval2.value == 'fah') {
        txtval2.value = txtval1.value;

      } else if (cboval2.value == 'cel') {
        txtval2.value = (parseFloat(txtval1.value) - 32) * 5 / 9;

      } else if (cboval2.value == 'kel') {
        txtval2.value = ((parseFloat(txtval1.value) - 32) * 5 / 9) + 273.15;
      }
      break;

      /* Si es Kelvin */
    case 'kel':

      if (cboval2.value == 'fah') {
        txtval2.value = ((parseFloat(txtval1.value) - 273.15) * 9 / 5) + 32;

      } else if (cboval2.value == 'cel') {
        txtval2.value = parseFloat(txtval1.value) - 273.15;

      } else if (cboval2.value == 'kel') {
        txtval2.value = txtval1.value;
      }
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

}

/* Y cuando se realice un evento en nuestro input o select, que ejecute nuestra función creada arriba */
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  txtconv1.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    /* Parametros ( primer combo a evaluar, segundo combo a evaluar, input que realizara los calculos, input que recibira los resultados ) */
    gz_convertir(cboconv1, cboconv2, txtconv1, txtconv2);
  });

  txtconv2.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    gz_convertir(cboconv2, cboconv1, txtconv2, txtconv1);
  });

  cboconv1.addEventListener('change', function() {
    gz_convertir(cboconv1, cboconv2, txtconv1, txtconv2);
  });

  cboconv2.addEventListener('change', function() {
    gz_convertir(cboconv1, cboconv2, txtconv1, txtconv2);
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>conversor</title>
</head>

<body>


  <input id="txtconv1" name="txtconv1" type="number">
  <select id="cboconv1">
    <option value="cel" selected>Celsius</option>
    <option value="fah">Fahrenheit</option>
    <option value="kel">Kelvin</option>
  </select>

  <p>=</p>

  <input id="txtconv2" id="txtconv2" type="number">
  <select id="cboconv2">
    <option value="fah" selected>Fahrenheit</option>
    <option value="cel">Celsius</option>
    <option value="kel">Kelvin</option>
  </select>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Soy nuevo en esto de stackoverflow y tambien en javascript, pero es esto lo que necesitas?

Comment: Hola! bienvenido, sería genial que compartas una explicación del código que compartes, ya que una respuesta de solo código, se considera de mala calidad :)

Comment: Muy buena respuesta Riaven, felicidades!

Answer (score -1):

Checa el código html y javascript corregido:

```js
var entrada; 
var inputSel;
var salida;
var outputSel;

function onChange(num) {
    if(num == 'uno') {

        entrada = document.getElementById('input1').value;
        inputSel = document.getElementById('sel1').value;
        salida = document.getElementById('input2');//Aquí pusiste la G en mayuscula...
        outputSel = document.getElementById('sel2').value;

    }else if (num == 'dos') {

        entrada = document.getElementById('input2').value;
        inputSel = document.getElementById('sel2').value;
        salida = document.getElementById('input1');//Aquí pusiste la G en mayuscula...
        outputSel = document.getElementById('sel1').value;

    } else {
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'error onChange function';
    }
}



function tempCalc(valNum) {

    valNum = parseFloat(valNum);

    if (valNum != 0) {
        if(inputSel == 'cel' && outputSel == 'fahr') {
            salida.value = (valNum * 9/5) + 32;
        }else if(inputSel == 'cel' && outputSel == 'kel') {
            salida.value = valNum + 273.15;
        }else{ //Aquí pusiste un else if sin parentesis, asumo que querias usar un else
            document.getElementById('error2').innerHTML = 'error tempCalc function';
        }
    }else {
        document.getElementById('error3').innerHTML = 'valNum es 0';
    }

}
```

```html
<div id='box'>

    <p class="temp-config">
        <!-- Aquí pusiste onChange y tempCalc 2 vecez, no es necesario -->
        <input id="input1" type="number" oninput="onChange('uno'); tempCalc(entrada);"> 
        <select id="sel1" onchange="tempCalc(entrada)">
            <option value="fahr">Fahrenheit</option>
            <option value="cel" selected="selected">Celsius</option>
            <option value="kel">Kelvin</option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <div id="igual">=</div>

    <p class="temp-config">
        <!-- Aquí pusiste onChange y tempCalc 2 vecez, no es necesario -->
        <input id="input2" type="number" oninput="onChange('dos'); tempCalc(entrada)">
        <select id="sel2" onchange="tempCalc(entrada)">
            <option name="fahrenheit" value="fahr" selected="selected">Fahrenheit</option>
            <option name="celsius" value="cel">Celsius</option>
            <option name="kelvin" value="kel">Kelvin</option>
        </select>
    </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Hola Riven, por favor, añade algo más de información en tu respuesta. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda a otros usuarios. Comprendo que has añadido comentarios en el código, pero son algo genéricos: ¿por qué las partes que quitaste o cambiaste no eran necesarias? ¿por qué (o cómo) solucionan el problemas los cambios? Lee [answer] para más información.